# How to call method on Browser shortcut keys?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project on HTML and javascript. On press Ctrl+P browser will print the web page (which it is displaying).To block this i am using

```
 e.preventDefault();
```

but when i tried to call my function after this, Printing of browser get enabled.
I want to block the browser printing pop-up and want to display my pop-up box.
How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

This should work (tested in Chrome, Safari and Firefox) ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zUt7X/)):

```
$(window).keydown(function(evt){ 
    if((evt.which == "80" && ( evt.metaKey || evt.ctrlKey ))){  
            evt.preventDefault(); 
            alert('not printing anything here');
    }  
});​
```

Further resources: http://h43z.blogspot.de/2012/11/whats-real-and-whats-not.html, http://labs.neohapsis.com/2012/11/14/browser-event-hijacking/, http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/12/how-script-kiddies-can-hijack-your-browser-to-steal-your-password/

edit: a no jQuery version:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown',function(evt){
    if((evt.which == "80" && ( evt.metaKey || evt.ctrlKey ))){  
            evt.preventDefault(); 
            alert('not printing anything here');
    }  
});
```

Comment: And since you're using `console.log()` will not work in older versions of IE ;)

Comment: @Stephan Bönnemann Thanks for response, can i write the above code in javascript.

Comment: @user1737342 you mean without jQuery?

Comment: @Shanky_Richer I posted it, sorry for asuming jQuery availability in the first place.

Comment: @Shanky_Richer would you mind paying back a little by upvoting and accepting the answer if it helped you, or provide further feedback if it still doesn't work?